# How to convert HTML page to plain text in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, screen-scraping

I know this has been asked before but I can't find a good answer for node.js

I need server-side to extract the plain text (no tags, script, etc.) from an HTML page that is fetched.

I know how to do it client-side with jQuery (get the .text() contents of the body tag), but do not know how to do this on the server side.

I've tried https://npmjs.org/package/html-to-text but this doesn't handle scripts.

```
  var { convert } = require('html-to-text');
    var request = require('request');
    request.get(url, function (error, result) {
        var text = convert(result.body, {
            wordwrap: 130
        });
    });
```

I've tried phantom.js but can't find a way to just get plain text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) and jQuery (server-side).

With jQuery you can delete all scripts, styles, templates and the like and then you can extract the text.

**Example**

(This is not tested with jsdom and node, only in Chrome)

```
jQuery('script').remove()
jQuery('noscript').remove()
jQuery('body').text().replace(/\s{2,9999}/g, ' ')
```

Comment: how do I delete the scripts? `$.find("script").delete()` generates a no-such-method error.` jsdom.env({
        url: url,
        scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
        done: function (errors, window) {
            var $ = window.$;
            $.find("script").delete();`

Comment: try `$('script').delete()`

Comment: "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'delete'" I'll ask this as separate SO question.

Comment: Sorry, `.delete` is not the right method, it's `remove()`. But generally you should first test the script in your browser (Chrome or FireFox or Safari, not MSIE!). In Chrome you can simply press Shift+Ctrl+I to get the Developer Tools. Load the page and in the Script tab test your script. Be aware that `$` might not be `jQuery`. To be safe use `jQuery` instead of `$`. And be careful not to delete the jQuery script too soon!

Answer (score 9):

For those searching for a regex solution, here is my one

```
const HTMLPartToTextPart = (HTMLPart) => (
  HTMLPart
    .replace(/\n/ig, '')
    .replace(/<style[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/style[^>]*>/ig, '')
    .replace(/<head[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/head[^>]*>/ig, '')
    .replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script[^>]*>/ig, '')
    .replace(/<\/\s*(?:p|div)>/ig, '\n')
    .replace(/<br[^>]*\/?>/ig, '\n')
    .replace(/<[^>]*>/ig, '')
    .replace('&nbsp;', ' ')
    .replace(/[^\S\r\n][^\S\r\n]+/ig, ' ')
);
```

Answer (score 7):

As another answer suggested, use JSDOM, but you don't need jQuery.  Try this:

```
JSDOM.fragment(sourceHtml).textContent
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use TextVersionJS (http://textversionjs.com) to generate the plain text version of an HTML string. It's pure javascript (with tons of RegExps) so you can use it in the browser and in node.js as well.

This library may work for your needs, but it's *NOT* the same as getting the text of an element in the browser. Its purpose is to create a text version of an HTML email. This means that things like images are included. For example, given the following HTML and code snippet:

```
var textVersion = require("textversionjs");
var htmlText = "<html>" +
                    "<body>" +
                        "Lorem ipsum <a href=\"http://foo.foo\">dolor</a> sic <strong>amet</strong><br />" +
                        "Lorem ipsum <img src=\"http://foo.jpg\" alt=\"foo\" /> sic <pre>amet</pre>" +
                        "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor <br /> sic amet</p>" +
                        "<script>" +
                            "alert(\"nothing\");" +
                        "</script>" +
                    "</body>" +
                "</html>";
var plainText = textVersion.htmlToPlainText(htmlText);
```

The variable `plainText` will contain this string:

```
Lorem ipsum [dolor] (http://foo.foo) sic amet
Lorem ipsum ![foo] (http://foo.jpg) sic amet
Lorem ipsum dolor
sic amet
```

Note that it does properly ignore script tags. You'll find the latest version of the [source code](https://github.com/EDMdesigner/textversionjs) on GitHub.

Comment: This appears to create a markdown-flavored string of the HTML content. I'm noticing that from how it interprets anchors with `href` and `alt` specified.

Answer (score -7):

Why not just get textContent of the body tag?

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var bodyText = body.textContent;
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but as future reference for others, node.js is a headless server running javascript, there is no document object (without using a lib and creating it manually). This answer appears to presume that the js is running in a browser.